# I need to short-time store associative data of unknown amount in Java

Tags: java, iot

I want to read different IoT tags in Java and send it to an MQTT server. I could just read the data and send it off through the network, but the data could come in once a few minutes as well as in a flood of occurrences several times a second. So I thought about buffering the data as key->value pairs and checking if a tag number already appeared and how long ago.

I don't know how many tags can appear.

In dynamic scripting languages I'd just use an array or json object like {tag_number: [last_seen, times_seen]} and check each time tagnumber appeared, I increase times_seen by 1 and if last_seen is older than 1 second, send the times_seen to the server in order to reduce network traffic if I get spammed by the tags that report occurrences.

The array supposed to be short-time, long time storage is done by the MQTT server.

Java however has no dynamically growing arrays, I need to declare them with a fixed amount of entries. What would be the best way to do that in Java? I don't need complete examples, just a hint what kind of datatype to use, or a class? Is a buffer class object the right way here?

Comment: an arraylist? a map? you've got tons of dinamically-growing structures in java

Comment: I suggest having a look at the collection framework, namely `List` and `Map` which act like a dynamically sized array resp. a key-value-object

Comment: Yes that's why I asked, I don't know which is best, most performant and most efficient way to do that.

Comment: If there's no key involved, no logic whatsoever (you just save them all, process them all), then an arraylist could be a good fit. Edit, just read about KV pairs --> use a map, as @RobCo says

Comment: A `HashMap` sounds like what you need. It is similar to json object or dictionary or associative array in other languages (key-value mapping).

Comment: @AsierAranbarri It'd need to be with an associative key so I can select tag_number and look how often tag_number appeared.

Comment: @RobCo yes that sounds like what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe **HashMap** is what you are looking for

Here if you want to see some example: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp